# the value of "?attr/colorPrimary"

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm learning to use the **Toolbar** widget.
while following the guide on `developer.android.com`, I find this

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

when I go to the definition of **"?attr/colorPrimary"**, I only find

```
<attr format="color" name="colorPrimary"/>
```

so how can I know the value of **"?attr/colorPrimary"**

Comment: You'll find the value in **colors.xml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- open **style.xml** and code for application theme like this

  ```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">

  </style>

  <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
      <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
      <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>

      <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
      <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
      <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
  </style>
  ```
- colorPrimary is defined in **color.xml**
- so **?attr/colorPrimary** value is equal to **@color/colorPrimary**

Answer (score 1):

The value "?attr/colorPrimary" in android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" is a syntax for “?attr/*”. Here *. i.e “colorPrimary is accessed from current application theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Color defined in Colors.xml for colorPrimary attribute is taken for your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply any color in toolbar.You can also create you costume toolbar just like toolbar.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    android:id="@+id/toolbar_common"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


    <com.peopleshopapp.custom_control.GothamBoldTextview
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/circled_logo_top"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_18"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/category_icon"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

post below in your style.xml

```
 <style name="Toolbar">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```